# Fetching an image (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to fetch the image from https://api-assets.clashroyale.com/cards/300/CoZdp5PpsTH858l212lAMeJxVJ0zxv9V-f5xC8Bvj5g.png
The code to fetch:

```
fetch('https://api-assets.clashroyale.com/cards/300/CoZdp5PpsTH858l212lAMeJxVJ0zxv9V-f5xC8Bvj5g.png', )
                .then(res => res.blob())
                .then(myBlob => URL.createObjectURL(myBlob));
```

The error:

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "obj" argument must be an instance of Blob. Received an instance of Blob
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at Function.createObjectURL (node:internal/url:960:13)
    at C:\Users\lars\OneDrive - CVO-AV\Documenten\GuideBot\src\Commands\clash.js:45:37
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

node version: v16.13.1

Comment: NodeJS does not have a native fetch (a pre-release is available in Node 17.5), so which fetch library are you using?

Comment: I am using node-fetch @Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that node-fetch doesnt [support .blob()](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/78) yet, so instead you will need to do it like the example in [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#streams):

```
const { pipeline } = require('node:stream');
const { promisify } = require('node:util');
const { createWriteStream } = require('node:fs');

const streamPipeline = promisify(pipeline)

const response = await fetch('https://api-assets.clashroyale.com/cards/300/CoZdp5PpsTH858l212lAMeJxVJ0zxv9V-f5xC8Bvj5g.png');
await streamPipeline(response.body, createWriteStream('./octocat.png'))
```

Wich returns the image correctly: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/950681875733708820/967324291161010216/unknown.png